# How to get exact position/coordinates of PowerPoint connectors using OpenXML?

Tags: .net, powerpoint, openxml-sdk

How can I get the exact position of the connectors in PowerPoint?
I'd like to understand whether my connectors (any type: curved, elbow, straight) are crossing any shape. 
I have all shapes and their positions, but I don't know how to check when the specified connector is crossing (overlapping) a shape or another connector.

Here is my example. I have such situation (example slide is created in Aspose, but there is no difference in the end, I face same issue)

[image]

As you can see - red curved connector is overlapping the 'Intersected shape' and I'm trying to identify such situation in order to adjust it a bit, e.g. to shift intersected shape to the left or to move shape 2 to the right.

In Aspose - the connector is having only Connector frame coordinates, but I have no clue where the actual red line is drawn. I got official confirmation from Aspose that they are not providing such functionality and are not planing to.
That's why I was checking OpenXML SDK, since it is native and should provide maximum access to all members of the presentation. 
The issue so far is quite a poor documentation for SDK, that's how I end up with question here.

Here is the sample code which I'm trying to complete:

```
using (PresentationDocument ppt = PresentationDocument.Open(docName, true))
            {
                PresentationPart part = ppt.PresentationPart;
                OpenXmlElementList slideIds = part.Presentation.SlideIdList.ChildElements;
                string relId = (slideIds[0] as SlideId).RelationshipId;

                SlidePart slide = (SlidePart)part.GetPartById(relId);

                if (slide != null)
                {
                    // Get the shape tree that contains the shape to change.
                    ShapeTree tree = slide.Slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree;

                    var connector = tree.GetFirstChild<ConnectionShape>();
                    var intersectedShape = tree.ChildElements.First(x => x.InnerText == "intersected shape") as Shape;

                    if (intersectedShape != null && connector != null)
                    {
                        //here I'd like to check if they are overlapping and then e.g. to shift intersectedShape a bit to the left
                    }
                }
            }
```

In connector XML itself I see only information about Ids (of shapes to which it is connected) and Idx (which is the side/endpoint of the shape to which it is connected).

Is it feasible at all what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Your question should have your effort to solve the task. Code is good, environment, screenshots, error codes if any. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov, I've updated my question. Hope it shed more light.